# BigCommerce Stencil Custom Page template not appearing

Tags: bigcommerce

In Page Builder I've added a page called About Us which has the url '/about-us/'

I've been following the instructions found here

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/storefront-customization/custom-templates

in order to make a custom template for that page.

I made a file called about-us.html in templates/pages/custom/page with the contents:

```
<h1>About Us Page Test</h1>
```

My .stencil file looks like the following

```
{
  "normalStoreUrl": "my url",
  "accessToken": "my access token",
  "port": "3003",
  "customLayouts": {
    "brand": {},
    "category": {},
    "page": {
      "about-us.html": "/about-us/"
    },
    "product": {}
  }
```

}

I've stopped and reran 'stencil start' but every time I visit localhost:3003/about-us/ it just shows the normal page instead of the custom template I build.

Is there something I'm missing? Is this an issue with using the page builder in combination with stencil?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you haven't set the custom template for your page yet.

Go to Web Pages and edit your About Us page then look for the Template Layout File dropdown. Your custom template should appear there if it is setup correctly.

Comment: I was running this locally so I had no theme editor to work with. The issue was resolved after I performed a system reboot. Not sure why stopping and restarting stencil didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when a full system reboot was performed. I'm not sure why stopping and restarting stencil did not resolve this.